# R: replacing a table column with a modified version of that column

Tags: r, replace

I am using R currently and I have produced a table with 3 columns. The first column contains names looking like "XXX_YYY_ZZZ" and I would only want to keep the "XXX" part. This is why I tried `gsub`, but couldn't make it so I turned to `strapplyc()`, which works but produces only one column. Apparently, I would want to keep my initial table, but with the first column replaced by the `strapplyc()` output. Or any other different approach you think would fit better!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `data <- data.frame(col1 = c("XXX_YYY_ZZZ", "XXX_YYY_ZZZ"))`

    `data$col1 <- gsub("_YYY_ZZZ", "", data$col1)`

Comment: You should provide us the code you've tried, anyway you can pass the `data$col` to `gsub` and that should be fine

Answer (score 2):

Since you have NOT showed samples so creating a simplex example here for testing it.

```
cal1 <- c("XXX_YYY_ZZZ","XXX_YYY_ZZZ")
gsub("_.*","",cal1)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> gsub("_.*","",cal1)
[1] "XXX" "XXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Here is a regex which looks for three groups of text, separated by underscores. The `^` indicates start of string and `$` indicates end of string. I capture first (`\\1`) group, but there's nothing stopping you from capturing `\\2`, `\\3` or even `\\1\\3`.

```
gsub("^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$", "\\1", "XXX_YYY_ZZZ")

[1] "XXX"
```

You could also use `strsplit`.

```
> strsplit("XXX_YYY_ZZZ", "_")[[1]][1]
[1] "XXX"
```

Comment: I am sorry. I literally started programming in R a few days ago, so excuse me needing "how to basic" intructions! But I see you all use the hypothetical "XXX_YYY_ZZZ". Maybe I misunderstand something, but it would be impossible for me to type it for every single row of the column.

Comment: what's your data like? please edit your question adding the output you get from `dput(your_data)`, if you can.

Comment: @WannaBee replace the string with column, e.g. `gsub(..., "\\1", xy$column1)`.